# Loops Help in Python... reordering cards in a specific order

Tags: python

So, I wrote the program below in python that creates a deck of playing cards.

```
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  # creates an empty List
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)
print (deck)
```

Now, with the use of minimal lists, I want to make my program so that the original first card is first, the original last card is second, the original second card is third, the original second last card is fourth and so on until all cards are in their new places. How should I achieve this?

The things I have learnt are sort, reverse, remove, index, count, and pop

Thanks for helping! :)

Comment: add expected output and what is "original first card"?

Comment: I have never learnt that, this is a school homework that I am stuck on.

Comment: Can you use loops or only list enumeration? hint: even/odd location

Comment: @Roim yep, I can use loops as well but I am not sure how to

Comment: @Matthias we have not yet learned that, I tried it and asked my supervisor, he said no.

Comment: If you have `suits` and `values` it's a one-liner: `deck = [[f'{v} of {s}' for v in values for s in suits].pop([0, -1][i%2]) for i in range(len(suits)*len(values))]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by traversing half of the list and adding values from both start and end:

```py
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  # creates an empty List
for s in suits:
    for i in range(len(values)//2 + 1):
        card_from_start = values[i] + " of " + s
        deck.append(card_from_start)
        if i < 6:
          card_from_end = values[(i + 1) * -1] + " of " + s
          deck.append(card_from_end)

for card in deck:
    print(card)
```

It will produce the following output:

```py
Ace of Clubs
King of Clubs
2 of Clubs
Queen of Clubs
3 of Clubs
Jack of Clubs
4 of Clubs
10 of Clubs
5 of Clubs
9 of Clubs
6 of Clubs
8 of Clubs
7 of Clubs
... # and so on
```

Comment: oh ok! Thank you so much! Is there any way I could get rid of the len in "for i in range(int(len(values)/2)".. i haven't learnt that and wanna know more about it before using it.. thanks for your help

Comment: `len()` is just a function which returns length of the list passed to it. In our case, there are 13 elements in `values` list so it will return 13. So, you can just write 13 here.
**Edit:** I missed `+1`. So, the original is `for i in range(len(values)//2 + 1)` and if you don't want to use `len()`, it becomes `for i in range(14)`

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following with deque:

```
from collections import deque

suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  # creates an empty List
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)
new_deck = []
deque_deck = deque(deck)
while deque_deck:
    new_deck.append(deque_deck.popleft())
    new_deck.append(deque_deck.pop())
print (deck)
print(new_deck)
```

The output of `new_deck`would be:

```
['Ace of Clubs', 
'King of Spades', 
'2 of Clubs', 
'Queen of Spades', 
'3 of Clubs',
...
```

The logic is easy:
Take the first card from the deck and add it to the new deck.
Take the last card from the deck and add it to the new deck.
Repeat until your original deck is empty.

In case you are not allowed to use deque:

```
while deck:
    new_deck.append(deck.pop(0))
    new_deck.append(deck.pop())
print(new_deck)
```

Basically the same only with pop.

Comment: In case there are odd number of elements in `deck` it may throw `IndexError`. e.g.: `IndexError: pop from empty list`

Answer (score 1):

We can treat this deck of cards as a stack. We need to get top and bottom card of this stack at alternative step until the stack is empty.

So, at even occurrences we need to get the bottom card of the deck and at odd occurrences we need to get the top card of the deck. We want to repeat while there are elements in the original list.

We may use `list.pop()` method to get element from a list at a desired index. Documentation on `pop()` method can be found in the [Python Official Tutorial on Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

I have implemented this logic in the following code base:

```
import json


suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  # creates an empty List
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)

print("Original List: ")
print(json.dumps(deck, indent=4))
print("")

sfuffled_deck = []

count = 0

while len(deck):
    if count%2 == 1:
        sfuffled_deck.append(deck.pop())
    else:
        sfuffled_deck.append(deck.pop(0))
    count+=1

print("Shuffled List: ")
print(json.dumps(sfuffled_deck, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
Original List: 
[
    "Ace of Clubs",
    "2 of Clubs",
    "3 of Clubs",
    "4 of Clubs",
    "5 of Clubs",
    "6 of Clubs",
    "7 of Clubs",
    "8 of Clubs",
    "9 of Clubs",
    "10 of Clubs",
    "Jack of Clubs",
    "Queen of Clubs",
    "King of Clubs",
    "Ace of Diamonds",
    "2 of Diamonds",
    "3 of Diamonds",
    "4 of Diamonds",
    "5 of Diamonds",
    "6 of Diamonds",
    "7 of Diamonds",
    "8 of Diamonds",
    "9 of Diamonds",
    "10 of Diamonds",
    "Jack of Diamonds",
    "Queen of Diamonds",
    "King of Diamonds",
    "Ace of Hearts",
    "2 of Hearts",
    "3 of Hearts",
    "4 of Hearts",
    "5 of Hearts",
    "6 of Hearts",
    "7 of Hearts",
    "8 of Hearts",
    "9 of Hearts",
    "10 of Hearts",
    "Jack of Hearts",
    "Queen of Hearts",
    "King of Hearts",
    "Ace of Spades",
    "2 of Spades",
    "3 of Spades",
    "4 of Spades",
    "5 of Spades",
    "6 of Spades",
    "7 of Spades",
    "8 of Spades",
    "9 of Spades",
    "10 of Spades",
    "Jack of Spades",
    "Queen of Spades",
    "King of Spades"
]

Shuffled List: 
[
    "Ace of Clubs",
    "King of Spades",
    "2 of Clubs",
    "Queen of Spades",
    "3 of Clubs",
    "Jack of Spades",
    "4 of Clubs",
    "10 of Spades",
    "5 of Clubs",
    "9 of Spades",
    "6 of Clubs",
    "8 of Spades",
    "7 of Clubs",
    "7 of Spades",
    "8 of Clubs",
    "6 of Spades",
    "9 of Clubs",
    "5 of Spades",
    "10 of Clubs",
    "4 of Spades",
    "Jack of Clubs",
    "3 of Spades",
    "Queen of Clubs",
    "2 of Spades",
    "King of Clubs",
    "Ace of Spades",
    "Ace of Diamonds",
    "King of Hearts",
    "2 of Diamonds",
    "Queen of Hearts",
    "3 of Diamonds",
    "Jack of Hearts",
    "4 of Diamonds",
    "10 of Hearts",
    "5 of Diamonds",
    "9 of Hearts",
    "6 of Diamonds",
    "8 of Hearts",
    "7 of Diamonds",
    "7 of Hearts",
```

I used `json.dumps()` to pretty printing the output.

This can be solved in different ways. As it is a tutorial task, I suggest to try each solutions of this problem.

**Updated code without len method and json**

```
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  # creates an empty List
for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)

print("Original List: ")
print(deck)
print("")

shuffled_deck = []

count = 0

while deck:
    if count%2 == 1:
        shuffled_deck.append(deck.pop())
    else:
        shuffled_deck.append(deck.pop(0))
    count+=1

print("Shuffled List: ")
print(shuffled_deck)
```

Output:

```
Original List: ['Ace of Clubs', '2 of Clubs', '3 of Clubs', '4 of Clubs', '5 of Clubs', '6 of Clubs', '7 of Clubs', '8 of Clubs', '9 of Clubs', '10 of Clubs', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Queen of Clubs', 'King of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', '2 of Diamonds', '3 of Diamonds', '4 of Diamonds', '5 of Diamonds', '6 of Diamonds', '7 of Diamonds', '8 of Diamonds', '9 of Diamonds', '10 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'King of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', '2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts', '5 of Hearts', '6 of Hearts', '7 of Hearts', '8 of Hearts', '9 of Hearts', '10 of Hearts', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Queen of Hearts', 'King of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Spades', '3 of Spades', '4 of Spades', '5 of Spades', '6 of Spades', '7 of Spades', '8 of Spades', '9 of Spades', '10 of Spades', 'Jack of Spades', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Spades'] 

Shuffled List: ['Ace of Clubs', 'King of Spades', '2 of Clubs', 'Queen of Spades', '3 of Clubs', 'Jack of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '10 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '9 of Spades', '6 of Clubs', '8 of Spades', '7 of Clubs', '7 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '6 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '5 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '4 of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', '3 of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', '2 of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts', '2 of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', '3 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', '4 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '5 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts', '6 of Diamonds', '8 of Hearts', '7 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '8 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '9 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '10 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', 'Jack of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', 'Queen of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', 'King of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts']
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! So is there any way to do this without lens() and json.dumps()?

Comment: Updated the answer by removing Len method and json dump. Both were optional.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `insert` instead of `append` then you can add new values in any position of list

```
deck.insert(0,v + " of " + s)
```

with this line you will add any new values to start of list and all data will be after